# React Redux initialState fetch from Api

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using JWT auth, when the user log in I store the token in the localstorage. How do I fetch the api with that token, so I can get the user details when the page 
loads for the first time.

I'm already using React Thunk for the async requests but I don't know how to set the initialState with an async request. However is it okay to set the localstorage in the reducers?

Comment: You should probably hold off on initializing your store until after these requests have been made. That's probably the easiest way to solve the problem and will keep your reducers simple. If this is not an option, you basically need to render a loading UI until these requests have been made and the store is populated with meaningful data.

Comment: @CoryDanielson But where should I do the fetch, I would like to fetch products too (it's an e-commerce) and store them to the state.

Comment: It's is OK to access localStorage in the initialState function of your reducer

Comment: You should probably work on a global loading state for the App that you can display until the requests are completed. You can render that UI, and then dispatch actions to trigger those requests. You'll want to fetch the products and whatnot in Thunks, and you can dispatch those thunks from shouldComponentUpdate in a component, or from your Router when you render the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to do something like this in your action:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const LOADING = "LOADING";
export const SUCCESS = "SUCCESS";
export const FAILURE = "FAILURE";
export const UPDATE = "UPDATE";
export const SUCCESSFUL_UPDATE = "SUCCESSFUL_UPDATE";

export const getSmurfs = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING })
  axios.get('http://localhost:3333/smurfs')
    .then(res => dispatch({ type: SUCCESS, payload: res.data}))
    .catch(err => dispatch({ type: FAILURE, payload: err}))
}
```

So you would start with a state of Loading which would change to Success or Failure depending on the response. Then in your reducer you would want to do something like:

```
import { LOADING, SUCCESS, FAILURE, UPDATE, SUCCESSFUL_UPDATE } from '../actions/index';

const initialState = {
  smurfs: [],
  loading: false,
  error: "",
  updateID: "",
  clicked: false,
  update: []
}

export default function reducer(state= initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        smurfs: [],
        loading: true,
        err: ''
      }

    case SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        smurfs: action.payload,
        loading: false,
        err: ''
      }
```

Basically when it is successful it will turn off the loading and display your returned data

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { getSmurfs, deleteSmurf, update } from '../actions/index';

import Smurfs from './smurfs';
import Form from './form';
import UpdateForm from './updateForm';

class SmurfsViewer extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getSmurfs()
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.smurfs)
        // if loading returns true then display loading smurfs..
        if(this.props.loading) {
            return (<h1>LOADING SMURFS....</h1>)
        }

        //if clicked resolves true then display the form to allow updating of the smurf that had its edit button clicked
        let form;
        if(this.props.clicked) {
            form = <UpdateForm />
        } else {
            form = <Form />
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <Smurfs smurfs={this.props.smurfs} deleteSmurf={this.props.deleteSmurf} update={this.props.update}/>
                {form}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mstp = state => {
    console.log("FROM VIEWER:", state)
    return {
        smurfs: state.smurfs,
        loading: state.loading,
        clicked: state.clicked
    }
}

export default connect(mstp, { getSmurfs, deleteSmurf, update })(SmurfsViewer);
```

So you need to send the state from Redux through the mapStateToProps(mstp) and connect methods. Then you can use them in the component and it will update your redux state as needed. Then just refer to them as this.props.getSmurfs or something along those lines

Comment: Here is a simple project I did in school for Redux. If you want a more in depth example https://github.com/TaylorBelk1/Sprint-Challenge-Redux-Smurfs/tree/taylorbelk/smurfs

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it, where would you do the fetch? Is it okay in the componentDidUpdate?

Comment: You would do the fetch in your action. Do you see where I did an axios.get call? Just replace that part with your fetch call. Basically the same thing. I will add to the answer to show you the component I brought the state into from Redux

Comment: I mean where would you call getSmurfs

Comment: On the edit you will see that I called it in the componentDidMount hook